# Is the clone function implementation of virtual CTOR problematic

Tags: c++, clone

I just read the concept of virtual constructor and clone function.

```
class Dog
{
public:
    virtual Dog* clone()
    {
        return (new Dog(*this));
    }
};
class YellowDog:public Dog
{
public:
    virtual YellowDog* clone()
    {
        return (new YellowDog(*this)); //default Copy ctor is shallow copy. 
    }
};

void foo(Dog* p)
{
    Dog* c= p->clone(); 
}

int main()
{
    YellowDog d;
    foo(&d);
}
```

Does the above piece of code have a problem?
Assuming  `YellowDog d` created in main is holding a resource.
Inside `foo` the `c` would be pointing to a cloned object which points to the same resource.
So, if we call `delete` on `c`, then `YellowDog d` in main will not be able to access the same resource which it thought its holding
Is not it a problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "holding a resource"?

Comment: My bad while asking. Corrected

Comment: *"Is not it a problem?"* - Yes, ownership management is a problem. That's what gave birth to smart pointer classes. In fact that's why there are *standard* smart pointer classes.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - [Co-variant return types](http://ideone.com/C7Tn16). I think it's mostly a matter of style now.

Comment: @Bathsheba : I have not written the complete class. But what i meant by "holding a resource is" : a member variable of type pointer in a class pointing to a resource or a string or some object etc. which will not be accessible to YellowDog d in main once the delete is performed on Dog* c

Comment: @Some programmer dude : Yes i'm hiding the parent class function. That's called(as i learnt) covariant types. But either ways there is still the problem pointed out

Comment: why negative vote?

Comment: I feel it is not truly cloning if both instances share a resource

Comment: @anurg86. Don't comment your own question, but **edit your question** to improve it

Comment: Your base class is missing a virtual destructor!!! Minor point: Rather than `virtual YellowDog * clone ()`, you should write `YellowDog * clone () override`. Make your clone method const (`virtual Dog * clone () const`). And try to use smart pointers rather than raw pointers.

Comment: Btw, the object's missing a virtual destructor is the answer to the problem you raise in your question. If there were a virtual destructor, this virtual destructor would be called polymorphically when the object is deleted, and since is virtual, an object of the correct class gets deleted. This does not have to do anything with the `clone` method. The same problem arises if you write `Dog * dog = new YellowDog {}; delete dog;`.

Comment: @JohnB : How is virtual destructor realted to my question? the question im asking is related to two pointers pointing to same resource. There is no leak but dangling pointer. What you are referring to is virtual destructor and leaks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of managing resources owned by class instances is not exclusive to this case. It has to be handled in the copy constructor and the assignment operator.

The can be handled in various ways:

1. You can forbid copy by making those functions inaccessible. But it also means removing the clone() functions.
2. You can use explicit sharing. Every copy share the same resource and the last one to be destroyed release the resource. This means you have to set some reference counting mechanism.
3. You can copy the resource. This is not always possible if the resource is unique and cannot be copied.

Answer (score 0):

> Inside foo the c would be pointing to a cloned object which points to the same resource

This is not true. The default copy constructor will copy all non-static elements, and you have none there. You have 0 variables inside your class, so your copy constructor will do nothing.

So, in this function:

```
void foo(Dog* p)
{
    Dog* c= p->clone(); 
}
```

`c` will not be pointing to the same object, unless you have pointers inside `Dog` defined and not cloned properly at some point.

Ironically, your objects are empty. So unless you throw in some variables in your classes, we're talking about empty objects here and there, and hence shallow vs deep copy is meaningless.

Comment: No, an object with a virtual member function (or destructor) usually has a [vtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) so has a non-zero size (quite often, the same as the size of a pointer)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I know. But copying will not copy that, and it doesn't count because it's not part of the discussion (copy-constructor actions).

Comment: But you say "your objects have a size of exactly sero" and it is false

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Actually I want the OP to understand that if there's nothing inside his class, then it's meaningless to talk about shallow/deep copies. vtable is an advanced topic for someone who doesn't know what a copy-constructor is. Would you propose a better way to mention this?

Comment: I get what you want, but it would be better to say *"Your objects are **empty**"* instead. *"Ironically, your objects have a size of exactly zero."* can easily lead one to the wrong conclusion that `sizeof(Dog) == 0`, which is false.

Comment: @StoryTeller Do you find it better now?

Comment: No, because the size would be non-zero even without a VTable.

Comment: @StoryTeller That's actually not true. Where would the size come from?

Comment: Also in C++ empty classes and structs size is 1 to ensure that 2 instances have different addresses.

Comment: @BenjaminT I tried this long time ago (`sizeof(struct{})`) in gcc and got 0 sizes. I'm actually surprised. Are you sure?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Yes. You must have tried in C where empty structs size is 0. This is not the case in C++.

Comment: [Yes, we are sure](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sizeof#2). The standard requires every class to be of non-zero size. C doesn't allow it however, and GCC does only with size 0 as an **extension**.

Comment: @StoryTeller It seems C does not even allow empty structs at all and structs with no named members are undefined behavior. You never stop learning.